# Programmatically detect function calls in R formulae, e.g. y ~ x + log(z), and surround them in backticks

Tags: r

Let me explain my goal first because while the title expresses my strategy, I don't think it is likely to be the only way to solve the problem.

I have an R function to which I pass fitted model objects, like those from `lm`, and the function extracts the model frame, saves that as a data frame, standardizes the variables in the new data frame, then refits the model with the standardized variables to ease the interpretation of the model's coefficients.

Example code without wrapping it in a function:

```
mod <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

new_data <- model.frame(mod)

new_data <- data.frame(lapply(new_data, FUN = scale))

standardized_mod <- update(mod, data = new_data)
```

Now a summary of `standardized_mod` by virtue of being fitted with standardized data will give standardized coefficients.

This isn't the most efficient way of doing things, I admit, since I could do something like multiplying the estimates and SEs by each variable's standard deviation. But in the context of the function, I'm trying to be more flexible; this gets less straightforward when working with `survey` package objects and the like. I also use the same logic to fit models with interaction terms for simple slopes analysis. But this is besides the main point of the question, I just want to offer some explanation to avoid getting bogged down with "there's other ways to standardize coefficients" responses. I'm more interested in this general problem with formulae than the specific application.

The solution above falls apart when a function is applied to any of the variables. For example,

```
mod <- lm(mpg ~ log(wt), data = mtcars)

new_data <- model.frame(mod)

new_data <- data.frame(lapply(new_data, FUN = scale), check.names = FALSE)

standardized_mod <- update(mod, data = new_data)
```

This will break on `update(mod, data = new_data)`, because `lm` is going to look for a column called `wt` to apply `log` to in `new_data`, which only has columns called `mpg` and `log(wt)`.

What I would like to do is manipulate the model formula in such a way that it goes from `mpg ~ log(data)` to `` mpg ~ `log(data)` ``. Of course, if it was just `log` I was worried about, I might be able to get something really hacky going to address it. But I'd like to be able to do the same regardless of the function in the formula, like if it's `poly` or some such.

Here are some solutions I've considered:

- Instead of `update`, re-fit the model with `lm` directly and use the `.` for the RHS of the formula. This would work for some cases, but has big drawbacks, too. This will ignore any interaction terms in the original formula or other arithmetic uses of the formula from the original model. It also won't fix the problem if the function was applied to the LHS of the formula in the original model.
- Use some kind of convoluted regex matching to isolate terms that appear to be functions on the basis of being right before (, but as a general rule I'm fearful of using string manipulation since it may fail in confusing ways. I'm not completely ruling this route out, but I haven't wrapped my head around how to do it safely and am not sure how to match terms with functions without accidentally capturing other parts of the formula.
- I've tried messing around with the `terms` object and trying to use that as a way to use `update` on the formula itself, but haven't had much luck figuring out how to edit the `terms` object in the right ways.

Comment: What is your motivation for standardizing the log-transformed IV? That's a bit unusual.

Comment: I would agree that it's a bit unusual and the standardization of log-transformed IVs may not lend the interpretability that it would seem to (it's hard to intuit SDs of the log of something). With that said, I want the user to be able to decide—and many of the same challenges with formula manipulation re-appear even when the goal is to *not* standardize log-transformed predictors while still transforming others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can avoid having to re-create the formula like this.  `mm0` is the model matrix columns except for the intercept.  `scale` that giving `mm0_std0`.  Now compute the new standardized `lm`:

```
mod <- lm(mpg ~ log(wt) * qsec, data = mtcars)
response <- mod$model[1]
mm0 <- model.matrix(mod)[, -1]
mm0_std <- scale(mm0)
mod_std <- lm(cbind(response, mm0_std))
```

If you do want the formula this will give it:

```
formula(mod_std)
## mpg ~ `log(wt)` + qsec + `log(wt):qsec`
## <environment: 0x000000000b1988c8>
```

Comment: My example code contained a mistake as it should have included the `check.names = FALSE` argument, causing a failure for a different reason than I meant to convey (I've edited the OP).

With that said, the reason I resist this particular solution—which solves the toy problem here—is that if the original formula contained product terms, e.g., `mpg ~ log(wt) * qsec`, the new model fit with this method will use this formula: ``mpg ~ `log(wt)` + qsec``, losing the interaction.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Perfect! I'd forgotten I had `model.matrix` in my toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of another potential solution as well, but I've not extensively tested it and it uses regex, which is in my understanding not the most R way of doing things.

```
mod <- lm(mpg ~ log(wt) * qsec, data = mtcars)

new_data <- model.frame(mod)

new_data <- data.frame(lapply(new_data, FUN = scale), check.names = FALSE)
```

We have the usual start, above.

Now I pull the variable names from the terms object.

```
vars <- as.character(attributes(terms(mod))$variables)
vars <- vars[-1] # gets rid of "list"
```

And save the full formula as a string.

```
char_form <- as.character(deparse(formula(mod)))
```

Now I iterate through the variables and use regex to surround *each* one in backticks. This gets around the trickier regex I was worried about with regard to detect which variables had functions applied.

```
for (var in vars) {

    backtick_name <- paste("`", var, "`", sep = "")
    char_form <- gsub(var, backtick_name, char_form, fixed = TRUE)

}
```

If I want to specify a variable not to standardize, like the outcome variable, I can exclude it from the `vars` vector programmatically. For instance, I can do this:

```
response <- as.character(formula(mod))[2]
vars <- vars[vars != response]
```

Of course, we can remove the response by dropping the first item in the list, but the above is for demonstrative purposes.

Now I can refit the model with the new data and new formula.

```
new_model <- update(mod, formula = as.formula(char_form), data = new_data)
```

In this narrow case, I don't really need to use `update` since I have all I need for `lm`. But if I was starting with a `glm` object or some other model, other user-supplied arguments like `family` are preserved.

*Note*: Weights and offsets can be problematic here, but it's not an intractable problem. I think the most straightforward thing to do is explicitly exclude columns named "(weights)" and "(offset)" from the model frame before scaling, then `cbind`ing it back together afterwards. Then the user can use conditionals or some such to decide when to supply `` weights = `(weights)` `` and `` offset = `(offset)` `` arguments to `update`.